# Using methods and rerendering React Components in array

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a parent React Component that has a state containing some number of instances of a `React.Component` class. I'm doing it like this because there's several methods on these children classes that I need to reach and call in difference cases. Here is a simplified example showing this

```
interface ChildState {
    foo: number
}

interface ParentState {
    children: Child[]
}

class Child extends React.Component<{}, ChildState> {
    public constructor(props: {}) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            foo: 1
        }
    }

    public increase(): void {
        this.setState({
            foo: this.state.foo + 1
        })
    }

    public render(): JSX.Element {
        return <div>{this.state.foo}<br/></div>
    }
}

class Parent extends React.Component<{}, ParentState> {
    public constructor(props: {}) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            children: [
                new Child({}),
                new Child({}),
                new Child({})
            ]
        }
    }

    public render(): JSX.Element {
        return <div>
            <button
                onClick={() => {
                    for (const child of this.state.children) {
                        child.increase();
                    }
                }}
            >
                Increment
            </button>
            {this.state.children.map((child, index) => <div key={index}>{child.render()}</div>)}
        </div>
    }
}
```

I can put a confirm that `Child.increase` is getting called with a `console.log`, but the actual state variable `foo` of all the children isn't changing. Why is the state not being affected in these children?

Also, will I need to worry about calling `render()` again once those states can be updated correctly?

Comment: Quite a bit wrong here. First of all you should never have components as state. I'm suprised this even passes eslint/TypeScript checking. Second, you never want to `new` components either. This should be done exclusively by react as it warrants mounting/unmounting components to the dom/vdom. class components are a bit of a trap because it insinuates components behave OOP where in reality they exist together in more of a functional manner.

Comment: You are not supposed to do that, where did you get the idea of doing this? Creating a Child with `new Child` instead of `<Child />` and then calling render on the child instance, I've never seen any documentation doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps but you pass props from parent to child, parent  can pass behavior as props as well (a function that's called when a button is clicked called increase).

When Children share state you can [lift state](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) use context or redux.

```js
class Child extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <button
        onClick={() => this.props.increase(this.props.id)}
      >
        {this.props.count}
      </button>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    counters: [0, 0, 0],
  };
  increase = (
    index //arrow function (correct this binding)
  ) =>
    this.setState({
      counters: this.state.counters.map((count, i) =>
        i === index ? count + 1 : count
      ),
    });
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.counters.map((num, index) => (
          <Child
            count={num}
            key={index}
            id={index}
            increase={this.increase}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<div id="root"></div>
```